# How to fetch Tag name using Cheerio from and XML data (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, xml, cheerio

I have an xml data from which I want to be able to fetch tagnames and store them or run operations based on whether a particular tag is present in data

Eg XML Data:

```
<MyData version="3.0">
<StudentData type="Table">
    <Student type="Table">
        <StudentValue type="Table">
            <DateOfBirth type="Data">2009-05-31</DateOfBirth>
            <StudenClass type="Data">Sixth</StudenClass>
            <StudentRoll type="Data">006</StudentRoll>
            <Name type="Table">
                <FirstName type="Data">MMMMM</FirstName>
                <LastName type="Data">XXXXXXX</LastName>
            </Name>
            <Performance type="Table">
                <Level type="Data">Honor</Level>
            </Performance>
        </StudentValue>
        <Contact type="Table">
            <Email type="Data">xyx@xyz.com</Email>
        </Contact>
    </Student>
</StudentData>
```

I am able to however fetch the values & attr as shown in below code I have been using till now:

```
xml= '<MyData version="3.0"><StudentData type="Table"><Student type="Table"><StudentValue type="Table"><DateOfBirth type="Data">2009-05-31</DateOfBirth><StudenClass type="Data">Sixth</StudenClass><StudentRoll type="Data">006</StudentRoll><Name type="Table"><FirstName type="Data">MMMMM</FirstName><LastName type="Data">XXXXXXX</LastName></Name><Performance type="Table"><Level type="Data">Honor</Level></Performance></StudentValue><Contact type="Table"><Email type="Data">xyx@xyz.com</Email></Contact></Student></StudentData></MyData>';


var xmlData = cheerio.load(xml, {
  ignoreWhitespace: true,
  xmlMode: true
});

var studentName =   xmlData('MyData StudentData Student StudentValue Name').eq(0).text();
var attr =  xmlData('MyData StudentData Student StudentValue Name').eq(0).attr();
var find = xmlData('MyData StudentData Student StudentValue Name').get(0).tagname;


console.log(studentName);
console.log(attr);

console.log(find);
```

So How do I go about fetching and storing values like the tagname "Performance" under StudentValue Tag. 
Also I would like to do some actions based on a tagname/elements presence.

Like in JSON we can code in the below manner, in case of cheerio do we have something like this:

```
    if (MyData.StudentData.Student.StudentValue.hasOwnProperty('Performance'){
    //then do some actions
    console.log("Student is an Honor Student");
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: @pguardiario: I am looking to be able to store the tagname such as Performance as shown in the xml data above. I am not able to do so.

Comment: I am able to fetch the values such as Honor etc but not the tag name in itself

Answer (score 1):

You can get a tag name in cheerio like this

```
$('a').first().prop('tagName')
```

Comment: Hi @pguardiario, thank you for the answer, sorry I am novice here with this, how do we check is a tagname is present.
Something like check if under the studentvalue path if there is a child tag called Performance and if so i would store the value of the Level tag within it

Comment: Hey I got the answer thank you: xmlData('MyData StudentData Student StudentValue').children().get(4).tagName;

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can get the children tagnames

```
xmlData('MyData StudentData Student StudentValue').children().get(4).tagName;
```